# MikTeX Cannot Open DDE Link

Tags: miktex, acrobat

Age old question

In MikTeX, I encountered

"Cannot Open DDE Link to:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
Service: acroview
Topic: control
DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead")',"acroview","control");

I have tried forums from past which says to change the version number but I could not find where to put it.  I am using WinEdt 5.5 and Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2021.007.20099 on Windows 10.  A picture of "Options" -> "Execution Modes" is here below.  Thanking you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the error dialogue pops up, WinEdt will open a file called "Acrobat OpenDoc.edt".  On line 106, change

```
DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead")',"acroview","control",0);
```

to

```
DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead")',"acroviewA21","control",0);
```